# Jquery.height() выдаёт 0

Tags: javascript, html, css

Столкнулся со странной проблемой. Хочу сделать скрипт который подстраивает высоту колонок под соседние. Но при проверке в момент выполнения скрипта высота всех найденных объектов получается 0. Скрипт в конце документа, использую `$(document).ready`, но всё равно это не помогает. Погуглил по поводу этого и единственное, что нашел - это выполнять функцию в `$(window).load`. В целом это помогает,но соответственно только при первой загрузке вкладки. При обновлении опять получаю 0. В соседнем чистом документе всё вроде работает нормально. Возможно в объектах у которых я пытаюсь получить имеется какая нить "Пометка", в стиле какого нибудь значения `display` или прочих тонкостей с которыми jquery не дружит?
(Даже стандартный div не работает как надо)

Фрагмент HTML:

```
<altblocks class="clear-container">
    <block class="col-sm-12...">
        ....
       <par>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipiscing elit</par>
    </block>
    <block class="col-sm-12...">
        ....
       <par>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipiscing elit</par>
</block>
```

css:

```
altblocks
{
    display: table-row;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}

block
{
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

JS:

```
function setEqualHeight(){
$("altblocks").each(function(){
    var row = $(this).find('block');
    var maxheight =0;
    var hmaxi =0;
    row.each(function(i){
        var h = this.clientHeight;
        if(h>maxheight){
            maxheight = h;
            hmaxi = i;
        }
    });
    row.each(function(i){
        el = $(this);
        var h = maxheight;
        var pt = parseInt(GetText(el.css('padding-top'),''));
        var pb = parseInt(GetText(el.css('padding-bottom'),''));
        h -= (pt + pb);
        el.height(h);
    });
});
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    setEqualHeight();
})
```

Ps. Максимально попытался урезать полотно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У элемента `display: table-row;` не может непосредственного child'a `display: block;` . Иначе DOM логично переглючивает, и результаты предсказать сложно. Попробуйте вместо табличных display, использовать `display: block;` для altblocks: результат аналогичный будет. Хотите интересной гибкой блочности - почитаейте про flexbox - концепция позволяет делать мегагибкую вёрстку, "правильные" контейнеры.

Comment: Спасибо,flexbox,похоже то, что доктор прописал.

Comment: Кстате, а чего там с поддержкой флексов на данный момент?

Comment: @pepel_xD да всё хорошо вроде. Опера мини не держит, остальное держит, при чём не самые свешие версии, даже IE